# Is it possible to open an existing SQLite database in a Phonegap-based mobile app?

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, io

I released an Android app a year or so ago. I used the base Android SDK and I handled data storage by using its standard SQLite database interface (which creates a SQLite database in the app's private disk space).

I've recently been looking into rebuilding the app from scratch using a cross-platform framework. In particular I've been looking at Phonegap/Cordova.

But what I haven't been able to figure out is if it's possible for me to update my existing app to a Phonegap app and have that new Phonegap app open the SQLite database generated by the old app. This is an absolute requirement because I don't want my existing users to lose their data.

I've done some research, but can't seem to find a straight answer to my question.

So, Is this possible? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: If you're releasing it as an update for android, you should be able to write a cordova plugin to interface with the sqlite database.